# MySQL Trigger, Before Insert: Update if already exists

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have an application, which cannot update rows, only insert them, but If something is already inserted into the database and it tries to insert a row, it generates a `duplicate key error`.

I tried to create a trigger for the underlying database table, so If it tries to insert a row that exists, it changes to update instead.
Something like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `Test`.`Job_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `Job` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Job(id, createdAt, updatedAt, `name`, 
    version, ...) 
    VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.createdAt, NEW.updatedAt, NEW.name, 
    NEW.version, ...)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    updatedAt=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `name`=VALUES(`name`), version=VALUES(version), ...;
END
```

But it generates an error on the first insert:

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'job' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I read that you can't change the same table in a trigger or a stored procedure. Am I trying to make something impossible? Changing an insert into to an update if the row is existing?

Comment: Could you live with `replace`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html: *REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.*

Comment: If you have access to the PHP code that has the SQL query script, check this doc for MySQL insert syntax when a duplicate is found: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html